# file extension being hidden but opening page link in raw php content?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to remove the file extension `.php` from my documents on my site so the URL will loke like this:
http://www.mysite.com/home/
instead of like this:
http://www.mysite.com/home.php

I've tried all sorts of mod_rewrite code and none of them have worked for me except this one:

```
#Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I dont know anything about `.htaccess` and I'm new to php so I basically can't figure this out. At the moment this is hiding the `.php` but its spewing the pages php content in raw format/text instead of executing like this:

```
<?php
    $page_title = "Home";
    include('includes/header.php'); 
    include('includes/mod_home/mod_intro.php');
    include('includes/copyrightbar.php'); 
    include ('includes/mod_login/login_form.php');
    include('includes/mod_home/mod_welcome.php');
    include('includes/mod_home/mod_platinum.php');

?>

<?php include('includes/mod_home/mod_starlight.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/mod_home/mod_diamond.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/mod_home/mod_newest.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/mod_home/mod_featured.php'); ?>
<?php include('includes/mod_home/mod_gold.php'); ?>


<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Why is this happening? I've followed all the online tutorials and everyone else seems to have no such problem. My server does support `.htaccess` and is running Linux.
My links still go to `home.php` for instance (do i need to change these?)

Comment: Please consider removing the long PHP code example - it is enough to explain what is happening, you do not have to show the code. I did not include this to my edit though.

Answer (score 0):

What you have missed is the `RewriteBase` command.
This is the code:

```
#Start rewriting after /
RewriteBase /
#ignore real directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#ignore real files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Rewrite the match to .php file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

There may be some reason PHP is not executed. So, for sure, try this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

You can instead rewrite to GET paremater page, just like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: what does parameter page do, could you explain that last code in a bit more detail please?

Comment: also i have tried the first code you gave me and it is still showing home.php as raw php content. although it is hiding/removing the .php extension. but any idea why it could still be showing home.php as raw php text?

Comment: Is there some other content in your `htaccess`? Isn't there some PHP file that reads others as text, isntead of `include`ing them?

Comment: The GET parameters are theese that go after the URL, much lile `http://google.com?**q=htaccess**`. Many sites use them for determining the page, but they hide them using htaccess. Then, upon `index.php` there is a `switch` that choses what to do.

Comment: no the htaccess file now just has the first bit of code you gave me and thats all. its '.htaccess' right?

Comment: Try this too: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php`